# Unhandled exception in mono while running NancyFx

Tags: c#, mono, ubuntu-12.04, nancy

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have the mono-runtime package installed.  On my windows machine my NancyFx self hosted application compiles fine with 1 warning but when I try to run it on my VPS I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one
of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 20):

I ran across the same problem when trying to run a Mono app (compiled in Xamarin Studio on my Windows machine) on an Ubuntu 14.04 Docker virtual. I did the same thing as you and installed `mono-runtime`, and after an hour or two of searching, was able to get it to work after installing `mono-complete`. However, that also brings down a few hundred MB of additional stuff. Finally I found the package that did the trick: `libmono-system-core4.0-cil` ([see here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmono-system-core4.0-cil)).

Hope that helps!

Comment: That appears to fix my problem too - thanks!  (big Windows VS solution, but includes a cmd line project that I'd like to run on Linux). So Mono Runtime doesn't include all the runtime libraries? d'oh!

Answer (score 0):

The Mono version available in the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories is very old. Try with a newer Mono (e.g. the one in Ubuntu 14.04) and see if that works.

Comment: I installed 14.04 but now I'm getting a ctor error on the Nancy self host dll.

Comment: The Nancy docs mention that self host works with Mono, so I guess someone who knows more about Nancy than me would need to troubleshoot it :-)

Comment: I'm currently working on troubleshooting another Nancy related issue, but to help here I've just solved the Ctor related one as part of the same issue.  Essentially, you can't put your nancy modules on your main program, it stops the mono runtime from seeing 'Main', the solution is to put your NancyModule derived classes in separate classes in the app, and leave Program.cs as a simple standard Command line stub.